# Center vertical annotations on the bars in a Google ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-visualization, column-chart

I am using the `annotations: {style: Line}` option in a Google ColumnChart to make the orientation of the annotations vertical. However, the annotations aren't centered horizontally on the bars (they're too far to the right). How can I center the vertical annotations on the bars?

This is demonstrated in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachelis/b5o8cuag/).

Comment: there aren't any standard options for annotation position -- you can move them manually -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48461981/5090771) that moves them down...

Comment: Thanks, WhiteHat! Add that as a replay and I'll mark it as the answer.